# How to use HTTP & HTTPS proxy along with OAuth2 with requests package in Python?

Tags: python, api, proxy, python-requests, oauth-2.0

I am using `requests` package in Python to call some APIs. I am behind a corporate firewall, so I was using proxies to access data from the APIs. But now I need to use OAuth2 as well. `Requests` does not support OAuth2 by itself, we have to use `requests-oauthlib` for that. But `requests-oauthlib` does not have option to use proxies (see its [documentation here](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#introduction)).

So, how can I use both OAuth2 and proxies? Although I prefer to use `requests` package for its simplicity, any method is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The session objects provided by requests-oauthlib inherit from requests.Session, so you can specify `proxies` on them the same way that you can on an instantiated `requests.Session()`:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

session = OAuth2Session(...)
session.proxies = {'all': 'http://my.proxy.url:3128'}

session.fetch_token(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest either modify the requests-oauthlib for your purpose to support Proxy or directly use requests API as writing oauth clients is not that difficult. It is same standard HTTP stuff